Deriving the Green's function for the D'Alembert operator from the Helmholtz equation with treatment of $\frac{\partial_t}{c}$ as a scalar
The 3-dimensional Green's function for the Helmholtz operator
$$(\Delta_x + \omega^2)G(x,x') = \delta(x-x')$$
is given by
$$G(x,x') = G(x-x') = -\frac{e^{\pm i \omega \|x-x'\| }}{4\pi \|x-x'\|}.$$
In polar coordinates and for $x'=0$, this simplifies to
$$G(r) = -\frac{e^{\pm i r \omega }}{4\pi r}.$$
Now, consider the D'Alembert operator, which is given by
$$\Box_x = \Delta_x - \frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2.$$
With some abuse of notation, this operator can be viewed as analogous to the Helmholtz operator with
$$ \omega^2 = -\left(\frac{\partial_t}{c}\right)^2.$$
Using this analogy, the Green's function for the D'Alembert operator can be derived as follows:
\begin{align*}
G(r,t) &= -\frac{e^{\pm i r (i \partial_t / c) }}{4 \pi r} \\
       &= -\frac{e^{\mp r/c \partial_t }}{4 \pi r} \\
       &= -\frac{\delta(t \mp r/c)}{4 \pi r}.
\end{align*}
In the last step, I used the fact that the differential operator generates translations and that $r$ and $t$ are independent variables. The translation for a convolution is expressed through the Dirac delta distribution.$^*$
With this knowledge, I can derive the known Green's function( the minus sign in the final expression should come from the sign convention of the D'Alembert operator).
$^*$:
$$ e^{a \partial_x}f(x) = f(x+a). $$
$$ \int \delta(x' + a) f(x - x') \, dx' = f(x + a). $$
There is of course a lot of abuse of notation and treating the differentiation in regards to time as a scalar feels rightfully wrong.
But how wrong is wrong?
How can I make this argument correct, to derive at the same conclusion in a fashion not so different then presented here.
This would be an easy intuition for this Green's function without making use of residue theorem.
The Helmholtz equation is a time-independent form of the wave equation.
And this seems to be a reversion. Any clues how to make this reversion mathematically sound? Maybe Fourier could do the trick? (That's why i used $\omega$ instead of the more often found $k$.)
Any general idea how I can justify this derivation or results that make this treatment better?

YES! Fourier transform in time! This converts the time-derivatives into multiplication by the frequency so you can solve the resulting Helmholtz equation then take the inverse Fourier transform. This is exactly what you’re trying to do when you treat a derivative as a scalar. In fact more generally, the spectral theorem says that for any self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, there is a unitary isomorphism converting that operator into a multiplication operator; in the special case of a derivative, this unitary operator is the Fourier transform.
The necessary rigorous details for what I’m about to do can be found in books treating tempered distributions (e.g Folland’s Real Analysis chapter 9.2, or his PDE book Chapter 0). Btw, I use the following convention for the Fourier transform:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f)(\omega)\equiv \widehat{f}(\omega):=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(t)e^{-2\pi i\omega t}\,dt,
\end{align}
with which the inverse transform is simply replacing the $-$ with $+$.
With this, in mind, let us consider the functions $f_{c}(\omega):=e^{2\pi i\omega c}$ for a fixed value of $c\in\Bbb{R}$. This is a bounded function and so it defines a tempered distribution via integration, and as a tempered distribution, its inverse Fourier transform is defined such that for all Schwarz test functions $\psi$,
\begin{align}
\langle (f_{c})^{\vee},\psi\rangle&:=\langle f_{c},\psi^{\vee}\rangle\\
&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f_{c}(\omega)\psi^{\vee}(\omega)\,d\omega\\
&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\psi^{\vee}(\omega)e^{2\pi i \omega c}\,d\omega\\
&=\psi^{\vee\vee}(c)\\
&=\psi(-c)\tag{Fourier-inversion theorem}\\
&=\langle\delta_{-c},\psi\rangle.
\end{align}
So, this shows that the inverse Fourier transform on $f_c$ is $\delta_{-c}$. Or in more common Physics notation, you might be familiar with this as $\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{2\pi i (t+c)\omega}\,d\omega=\delta(t+c)$. In particular, taking $c=0$, this shows that the inverse Fourier transform (and also the forward Fourier transform) of the constant function $1$ is the Dirac delta at the origin:
\begin{align}
\widehat{1}=1^{\vee}=\delta_0.
\end{align}
So, taking the inverse transform of both sides, we get $\widehat{\delta_0}=(\delta_0)^{\vee}=1$; in Physics notation this says $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\delta(\omega)e^{\mp 2\pi i t\omega}\,d\omega=e^{\mp 0}=1$, so it almost seems like the definition of the Dirac delta (but really all the work went into the equation above which essentially asserts Fourier’s inversion theorem).

Ok with all that preliminary stuff out of the way, we have the following: we’re looking for a tempered distribution $G(t,x)$ such that $\Box G=\delta_{(0,0)}=\delta(t)\otimes\delta(x)$, i.e the Dirac delta in $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}^3$ centered at the origin. Now, take the Fourier transform only in time. Then, the equation becomes
\begin{align}
\left(\Delta_x+\left(\frac{2\pi \omega}{c}\right)^2\right)\widehat{\phi}(t,x)=1\otimes\delta(x)
\end{align}
Using your knowledge of the fundamental solution of Helmholtz’s equation, we can solve this equation for each fixed $\omega$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\widehat{\phi}(\omega,x)&=-\frac{e^{\pm i\frac{2\pi\omega}{c}\|x\|}}{4\pi\|x\|}=-\frac{1}{4\pi\|x\|}f_{\pm\|x\|/c}(\omega).
\end{align}
So, now taking the inverse Fourier-transform in time, and using the previous result gives us
\begin{align}
\phi(t,x)&=-\frac{1}{4\pi\|x\|}\delta_{\mp\|x\|/c}\equiv-\frac{\delta\left(t\mp\frac{\|x\|}{c}\right)}{4\pi\|x\|},
\end{align}
as desired.

I carried around the speed of light purely because you did, but really, you should set it to $1$. In relativity, $c\neq 1$ is a very cumbersome choice of units.

Is use of $\delta$ as a function much more rigorous than OP’s initial approach? Proceeding formally, doesn’t one need to verify?

@Aruralreader doesn’t one need to verify what?

anyway, the reason I don’t want to work operator-theoretically as OP writes things (exponentiating the differential operator… which can be defined via Fourier transform also) is because I don’t feel like getting into nitty gritty details of the domains of the various operators.

Yes I knew that the derivative $\partial_t$ becomes (at least proportional to) $i\omega$ (depending on choice of Fourier transformation. I just wanted to make clear if there was more to it.

I also have a post regarding the translation operator through exponentiation of the derivative and showing this exactly via Fourier transformation. So this wasn't surprising at all. But many thanks.

I'm especially thankful for your addition regarding distributional notation in Schwartz space.
